# How to run x command for y seconds when condition is met in Python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have an application where I have to run a command for y number of seconds but only when a condition is met. 
As soon as time duration is up, then it should move to next line.

Example: Second=10

```
if i==1:
    print("Hello") # for 10 seconds
```

It should only print hello for 10 seconds and then move on.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Add a loop testing against elapsed time

Comment: Can you give an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the previous answer a bit:

```
import time
if i==1:
    starttime=time.time()
    while time.time() < (starttime+10):
        time.sleep(1) # <-- do not print hello too often !
        print("hello")
```

because otherwise it will print "hello" about 10,345,123 times by my estimate :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a time loop inside your conditional:

```
import time
if i==1:
    starttime=time.time()
    while time.time() < (starttime+10):
        print("hello")
```